# Basic algebra question regarding properties of the summation operator

Tags: mean, notation, mathematical-statistics

I admit that my algebra is rusty. Can someone please explain how the middle part of the top equation is transformed to the middle part of the bottom equation (both are highlighted in black).

[image: equation]

Comment: In other words, you are asking why $2\bar{x}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ = $n(\bar{x})^2$. Factoring out the common factor of $2\bar{x}$ reduces that to either $2\bar{x}=0$ or $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ = $n\bar{x}$.  Now, *what is the definition of $\bar{x}$?*

Comment: I flagged this question as off-topic. It is better posted in Math stack exchange.

Comment: Well, this was directly from a intro to econometrics text book. While I realize that it is a basic algebra question, I would imagine others who are reading intro to econometrics text books might come here looking for this type of question since the summation operator is a basic yet critical part of econometrics. I know I did.

Comment: The focus on econometrics here is puzzling; econometrics is a small subset of statistical science of interest mostly only to its practitioners and precisely nothing here is restricted to econometrics.... More seriously, the algebra of summation is certainly central to statistics, so I am happy to recommend including this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = n\bar x$$

so

$$2\bar x  \sum_{i=1}^n x_i =2\bar x \times n\bar x $$

$$=2n\bar{x}\times \bar x = 2n\bar{x}^2$$